# Creation of aliases for shell commands in neovim with lua

Tags: lua, alias, neovim

This issue exists for several neovim plugins, for the purposes of this inquiry we shall look at two prime examples.

1. Currently running `checkhealth mason` informs me that `tar: not available`. This is because my operating system (OpenBSD) uses the BSD variant of "tar", and not the Gnu variant. The Gnu variant can be installed seperately as "gtar", but in order for mason to use it, the command must be aliased as "tar". In bash this would be as simple as: `alias  tar="/usr/local/bin/gtar"`. But in order to do this in my `init.lua`, I would need the neovim's lua api equivocal. Which I have not been able to find.
2. Also currently in `checkhealth mason`, java is listed as `not available`. In my shell's rc file, I have aliased it to `alias java="/usr/local/jdk-17/bin/java"`. Same scenario, the java command needs to be aliased or defined in lua for nvim.

I have added the java bin directory to my neovim's path, but this does not work. As mason and neovim is still unable to locate the java executable. I have also attempted to create a local variable for tar. Just a simple `local tar="/usr/local/bin/gtar"`, which obviously didn't work to correct the problem.

I have reviewed neovim's lua api documentation and could not find anything to resolve the problem, and it does not appear there is a ready made solution for this issue.